# Bash script acts differently depending on what executes it

Tags: bash, shell, utorrent

I have a bash script which acts as a post-process script for utorrent-server that passes on variables to a media renamed called FileBot.

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
TORRENT_NAME=$1
TORRENT_PATH=$2
TORRENT_LABEL=$3
TORRENT_KIND=$4
TORRENT_TITLE=$5

/usr/share/filebot/bin/filebot.sh -script fn:amc --output "/mnt/Storage/" \
   --log-file "amc.log" --action move --conflict override -non-strict \
   --def music=n subtitles=en artwork=n xbmc="192.168.0.123" deleteAfterExtract=y \
     clean=y "ut_dir=$TORRENT_PATH" "ut_file=$TORRENT_NAME" "ut_kind=$TORRENT_KIND" \
    "ut_title=$TORRENT_TITLE" "ut_label=$TORRENT_LABEL" "ut_state=5" "seriesFormat=TV \
    Shows/{n}/Season {s.pad(2)}/{n} - {s00e00} - {t}" "movieFormat=Movies/{n} ({y})/{n} ({y})" \
 &>> /home/xbmc/run.log
```

If i run this script manually, it works as intended, however when uTorrent executes it, it returns "No such file or directory." via stderr. I originally had uTorrent calling this script directly however I was having the same issue.

Does anyone know what could cause this?

UPDATE (Permissions for all directories/folders):

```
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4096 Nov 27 23:52 /home  
drwxr-xr-x  20 xbmc xbmc 4096 Dec 15 21:46 /home/xbmc  
drwxr-xr-x  10 root root 4096 Oct 17 06:51 /usr  
drwxr-xr-x 218 root root 4096 Dec 13 15:32 /usr/share  
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4096 Dec 15 15:55 /usr/share/filebot  
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Dec 15 18:56 /usr/share/filebot/bin  
-rwxr-xr-x 1 xbmc xbmc 615 Dec 15 21:44 /home/xbmc/run.sh  
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 552 Dec 15 18:56 /usr/share/filebot/bin/filebot.sh
```

Comment: Which is the no-such-file? filebot.sh?

Comment: Can you tell us how you are executing it with uTorrent? Does it have the +x permission to execute standalone?

Comment: What is `TORRENT_PATH`? Is it an absolute path?

Comment: TORRENT_PATH is a parameter given to the script from uTorrent, i have verified the path is being given correctly by running the script used by uTorrent (it is stated in the uTorrent log) e.g /home/xbmc/run.sh "friends.s06e11.720p.bluray.x264-mrs.sujaidr.mkv" "/mnt/Storage/Downloads/Complete/TV/Friends Season 6 Complete 720p.BRrip.mrlss.sujaidr" "TV" "multi" "Friends Season 6 Complete 720p.BRrip.mrlss.sujaidr"


And i'd assume the no-such-file is filebot.sh as thats the only script being called there, also filebot.sh has +x

Comment: If it was `filebot.sh` that was not found, bash would say `run.sh: line 8: /usr/share/filebot/bin/filebot.sh: No such file or directory`.  If it doesn't say all that then it is probably `run.sh` that is not found.  Check the `run.sh` path, and perhaps add something to the beginning of the script to see if it is executed at all.

Comment: But its writing the error to run.log which is the stderr/stdout log file as stated in run.sh

Comment: It that case it sounds like something in `filebot.sh`.  Perhaps that script assumes some environment variables that are not set.

Comment: Possibly, but then why does it work when i manually execute the script rather than when uTorrent executes it...

Comment: Because you have the required environment variables set in your shell.

Comment: Ah ok, so what environmental variables could they be and how would i set them?

Comment: Check the `filebot.sh` script.  If it is something set in your `~/.profile` you could check that also, or use `env` to display all of your environment variables.

Comment: I believe that you are right, i looked in filebot.sh (The script which is called by run.sh) and it had used ${HOME} which i have no replaced with the absolute path. Just to check, would it still be ok to use symlinks?

Comment: Symlinks are fine, assuming the permissions allow access.

Answer (score 2):

Change the current working directory.

Comment: So, CD into "/usr/share/filebot/bin" and then call filebot.sh?

Comment: Worth a shot. Makes the environment the same

Comment: You could even plonk it at the top of the script

Comment: Is there anyway to record the output of the change in directory? So if it is failing to change, then we could know?

UPDATE: change in directory didn't work, it says "line 9: filebot.sh: command not found"

Comment: Also, i tried out putting directory info via: pwd >> run.log and ls >> run.log however nothing is written?!

Comment: After giving the absolute path to the logs, they do actually return the correct stuff:
/usr/share/filebot/bin
filebot.sh

Answer (score 1):

IF filebot.sh is the no-such-file, I suggest you to try with this:

```
    chmod -R a+x /usr/share/filebot/bin/filebot.sh
```

IF it is your run.sh,

```
    chmod -R a+x /home/xbmc/run.sh
```

You can try running filebot.sh as the owner. I think it worths a shot.

```
    chown YOURUSERNAME /usr/share/filebot/bin/filebot.sh
    chmod u+s /usr/share/filebot/bin/filebot.sh
```

Comment: Not only the scripts, but the folders. You cannot access to a folder's content if you don't have x permission in that folder. You should check that /usr, /usr/share, /usr/share/filebot, /usr/share/filebot/bin OR /home, /home/xbmc have x permission.

Comment: Could it be that filebot.sh is owned by root, should i chown it to my user?

Comment: if your filebot.sh has x permission for user, group and others, that is not the problem. Can you paste the output of `ls -ld /usr /usr/share /usr/share/filebot /usr/share/filebot/bin /home /home/xbmc` and `ls -l /usr/share/filebot/bin/filebot.sh /home/xbmc/run.sh`?

Comment: Please see original post for permissions

Comment: It isn't a permissions problem, so both scripts are being found. The problem should be in what your filebot.sh does.

Comment: Filebot.sh just runs java and the java class... It works fine when manually executed so this can't be the problem...

Comment: does utorrent receive the absolute path to run.sh?

Comment: Yep: /home/xbmc/run.sh "%F" "%D" "%L" "%K" "%N"

Comment: try this `chown YOURUSERNAME /usr/share/filebot/bin/filebot.sh` and then `chmod u+s /usr/share/filebot/bin/filebot.sh`. I will edit my answer.